# How does Windows 10 obtain the default DNS server?

Tags: dns, dhcp

Let's say I have a computer connected to a router:

Network: 192.168.0.0/24
Router: 192.168.0.1
PC: 192.168.0.2 through DHCP

The DNS setting is set to "Obtain automatically".

How does Windows know where to send the DNS request?

What is the default DNS server? Is it the default gateway or the immediate router's IP?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the DNS server obtained from the DHCP server (in your case hosted on the router) via DHCP option 6. Read more about DHCP options here: https://www.incognito.com/tutorials/dhcp-options-in-plain-english/

Comment: Thank you, one more question, if my router connects to the Internet through PPPoE then the default DNS server would be the ISP's right?

Comment: I don't think it is directly connected with PPPoE. Your router acts as PPPoE client and DHCP server. If your router is ISP provided it is likely to be preconfigured to give out ISP DNS address to it's clients.

Comment: In my home network, my ISP-provided router itself functions both DHCP and DNS server, so DHCP configures the end computers to also use the router as DNS server (192.168.1.1). Presumably, the router's DNS service forwards to the ISP's server.